# ADODB Connection string in Visual Basic 6

Tags: sql, vb6, adodb

I moved to a new Windows 7 PC and now I need to specify "Network Library=DBMSSOCN" in my connection string.  On my old Windows 7 PC, my connection string is 
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=;Data Source=;User ID=;Password=" and that works just fine.  However, on my new computer if I run that connection string I get the error message "[DBNMPNTW]Connection broken."  I know this is the DLL for named pipes.  For some reason my pc is defaulting to the named pipes dll instead of tcp.

I have a lot of old apps out there and don't want to have to change and recompile everything to work on my pc.  How do I change my system to default to tcp?  The only differences between the two pcs are:

1. Old - Windows 7 x86           New - Windows 7 x64
2. Old - SQL Server 2008R2    New - SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Click Start -> Run
Type cliconfg
click OK

Does Named Pipes have a higher priority than TCP/IP?

Alternatively, you could disable named pipes for SQL Server.  To do this:

Click Start -> Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server -> Configuration Tools -> SQL Server Configuration Manager
Expand SQL Server Network Configuration
Disable Named Pipes.

Comment: I ran the cliconfig and named pipes are disabled and the only enabled protocod is TCP/IP.

Comment: Also named pipes are disabled already on SQL Server.  The weird thing is that it seems to work fine on my local SQL Server but not any remote servers.  The remote servers also have Named Pipes disabled.